# Packaging issue with Maven project in STS

Tags: spring-boot

I have set up one spring boot project at STS IDE .
Getting issue with maven read with JDK 1.8 java version

I have restart the IDE

> Error - Project build error: Invalid packaging for parent POM
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.9.RELEASE, must be
>   "pom" but is "jar".

Comment: Try to add `<packaging>pom</packaging>` into your pom.xml and update.

Comment: yeah i did but it won't work

Comment: Did you add it under `project` node such as `<project>...<packaging>pom</packaging>...</project>`?

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.Capgemini</groupId>
  <artifactId>Java-API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringBootQuickStart</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. You should add it into your **parent pom.xml**.

Comment: How come can you please send me the snippet xml code for this